# Pegar todas as datas de um dia da semana

Tags: php, array

Tenho um código que pega todas as datas de um determinado dia da semana.

Ex.
5/06/2017 = Segunda Feira.

O código está funcionando perfeitamente. Más está limitado há apenas 1 dia da semana, eu gostaria de "passar" mais dias um array.

```
function dias($dia_semana, $mes, $ano)
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);

    for ($dia = 0; $dia <= $dias; $dia++)
    {
        $date->setDate( $ano, $mes, $dia );

        if ($date->format( "w" ) == $dia_semana)
        {
            $datas[] = $dia."/".$mes."/".$ano;
        }
    }

    return $datas;
}
print_r(dias("1","06","2017");
// "1"    = 0 = domingo até o 6 = Sábado 
// "06"   = mês
// "2017" = Ano
```

Queria passar um `array` no lugar de `$dia_semana`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente da seguinte forma:

```
function dias($dias_semana, $mes, $ano)
{
    $date = new DateTime();
    $dias = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes, $ano);

    for ($dia = 0; $dia <= $dias; $dia++)
    {
        $date->setDate( $ano, $mes, $dia );
        foreach ( $dias_semana as $_dia ) {
            if ($date->format( "w" ) == $_dia)
            {
                $datas[$_dia][] = $dia."/".$mes."/".$ano;
            }    
        }

    }

    return $datas;
}
print_r(dias([1,2],"06","2017"));

// Resultado
Array
(
    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 5/06/2017
        [1] => 12/06/2017
        [2] => 19/06/2017
        [3] => 26/06/2017
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [0] => 6/06/2017
        [1] => 13/06/2017
        [2] => 20/06/2017
        [3] => 27/06/2017
    )

)
```

P.S: Fiz a alteração na função somente para que a mesa funcione com um array, então sugiro que faça os devidos tratamentos e etc. Você também pode adaptar para a função receber um item ou um array.

Comment: perfeito amigo, obrigado pela resposta. vou adaptar com oque preciso, más inicialmente era este o problema.

Comment: Por nada, precisando estamos aqui! hehe

Comment: Raapaz, agora uma dúvida, se caso a não passar um array retorna um erro. Tem como eu tratar isso pra trazer o resultado, independente se é array ou string?

Comment: No PHP existe a função "is_array" você utiliza ela para verificar se o valor recebido é um array, ai é só você fazer o tratamento restante.

Comment: Heheheeh obrigado novamente !